# HTML iframe shows scrollbar during animation and then disappears. CSS overflow property is set to hidden

Tags: css, animation, iframe, scrollbar, overflow

I am building a Chrome extension which inserts an iframe onto the screen when activated. I have set the CSS property to hidden. The scrollbar is displaying during the animation (both ways), and it immediately disappears after the animation.

The animation wipes or scrolls the iframe onto the screen from the bottom edge of the browser window.

I am aware that the seamless property was removed from iframes in HTML5.

How can I prevent the scrollbar from displaying during the animations?

Comment: Could we see some code, and have you tried the `scrolling="no"` attribute on your `<iframe>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by doing the following in javascript after creating the iframe.

```
iFrame.scrolling = 'no';
```